# Unable to open a new tab in Ipad

Tags: javascript, ipad

I want to open a new tab after i have to close.

Could anyone help me how to open a new tab on click in ipad?

the following javascript is not working.

window.open('','_blank'); 
window.close();

Answer (score 0):

The method window open has the next syntax:

```
window.open(URL,name,specs,replace)
```

- URL  Optional. Specifies the URL of the page to open. If no URL is
  specified, a new window with about:blank is opened.
- name Optional.    Specifies the target attribute or the name of the
  window. The    following values are supported:

  1. _blank - URL is loaded into a new window. This is default
  2. _parent - URL is loaded into the parent frame
  3. _self - URL replaces the current page
  4. _top - URL replaces any framesets that may be loaded
  5. name - The name of the window (Note: the name does not specify the
     title of the new window)
- specs    Optional. A comma-separated    list of items, no whitespaces.
- replace  Optional. Specifies whether    the URL creates a new entry or
  replaces the current entry in the    history list. The following
  values are supported:

  1. true - URL replaces the current document in the history list
  2. false - URL creates a new entry in the history list

Try to change:

```
window.open("","_blank");
```

> *iOS Mobile Chrome is limited by iOS's API exposed to. So such
>   Mobile Chrome is not actually Desktop Chrome browser for example. As a
>   result Browser's Pop-up Blocker blocks window.open(). It blocks a new
>   tab.*